# Minimize the small loss to zero loss in transfer learning

Tags: deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am asking this question because I noticed in competitions people tend to minimize the loss to 0. I have an "image binary classification " problem and I already achieved the binary_crossentropy_loss to 0.003 with a "train from scratch" transfer learning model. How can I further reduce it to 0? Should I fine-tune the model again or should I go back to do image feature engineering?

[image: traning 8000 images per epoch with 1600 validations]

Additionally, according to the picture here, I suppose I encountered "vanished gradient" instead of "overfitting". If so, what should I do on the next step?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to perform image binary classification, if you can minimize both your training and validation loss to 0, that basically means your network is 'perfectly' trained to recognize all the validation images by using just the training images. When this happens, I think it's better for you to get 'harder' data for your network to learn.

From your image, I think you should continue training your model for more epochs, since val_loss does not seem to converge yet; as a result, there are no indications of 'overfitting'.

Regarding 'vanished gradient', it's not possible to tell from your picture since the common sign of vanishing gradients is weights dying down to 0. To check for this problem, I think you should keep track of the weights distribution of your model in addition to the losses.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't have access to harder data since it is a competition with a fixed dataset. I do realize that the small loss there is from some of the dark and not regular pictures in the test set. For the val_loss part, it never really converged even I add 40 epochs there because the validation set is over 10k and I can only set the step for validation like 2000 or it will be too slow. A step with 2000 will continue to fluctuate.

Comment: Then the competition's guidelines only require a validation steps of 2000 out of 10k? That may bring some variance issue into the results, since choosing 2000 randomly out of 10k may not be the best choice. If the reason is due to your hardware, maybe you can consider keeping the 2000 validation samples fixed (e.g. choosing both easy and hard samples) to allow the validation loss to converge?

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that it helps you.